# Requesting specific information from Twitter

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I'm looking to pull the latest posts from a series of specific users.  In order to reduce the request size and improve speed I want to request from Twitter ONLY a specific set of information, such as "screen_name", "id" and the text itself.  At the moment it pulls a whole set of unnecessary data which I don't require.

Does the API allow you to structure specific requests in this manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, seems that the twitter APIs doesn't allow you to select a specific set of informations from results. They allow you to limit the number of tweets result to return per page through the optional rpp parameter. 
So, you should parse the content fetched by twitter servers and pull out a whole set of informations you need. You could also use an intermediate server which is responsable to fetch the content and return you what do you need. Don't forgot the [limits](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting).